# Multibranch Jenkins pipeline stop scanning for Jenkins file in all branches

Tags: git, jenkins

I have set up a multibranch Jenkins pipeline with Gitlab. There are around 250+ branches in the Gitlab repository. The scanning part in the multibranch Jenkins pipeline is taking too much time. Since as of now I am only concerned with the dev and master branches. Is there any way we can limit the scanning to only specific branches to improve the runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins can filter branches in a multibranch pipeline by name using a wildcard or regular expression.

Here find the screenshot:

[image]